# How to put some data(hash) in Ethereum blockcahin?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

how to put some data (i want to put in. something like 'ABFFC1244AA') 
in Ethereum blockchain ?

as i know there is *'data' variable* in transcation .

also if i can, want to know example or link for how to do it.

i make *'geth'* network in ubuntu server.

and i can just make account , mining , send transaction ,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to the we3js document here for sendTransaction: http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction

You may include a `string` as an optional parameter named `data` in sendTransaction. This data will be embedded in the transaction in the form of HEX. You will need to use web3.utils to convert it back to string for readability.